# Miraak NEVER absorbs any dragon souls in 'At the Summit of Apocrypha' quest

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

I've been playing the Dragonborn DLC for awhile. Now, I'm in the '*At the Summit of Apocrypha*' quest. The issue I'm encountering is the bug where Miraak NEVER absorbs any dragon souls, leaving him permanently ethereal during the fight, not allowing me to finish the quest. And my character is ALWAYS absorbing the dragon souls.

I've been finding possible solutions on the Internet. Here's what I've already tried:

- Installing Unofficial Skyrim and Dragonborn Patch
- Uninstalling Unofficial Skyrim and Dragonborn Patch
- Kill all dragons before attacking Miraak
- Using the ff. console commands:

  - `setstage DLCMQ06 500`
  - `setstage DLCMQ06 580`
  - `resurrect`
  - `resethealth`
  - `disable` and `enable`
  - `tcl`
- Sneaking behind stone pillars, pile of books, and behind Miraak
- Resetting and reloading a save game
- Followed EVERY known Youtube videos of Bugfix
- Use of petty weapons and armor
- Changing the difficulty
- Reinstalling the game

Comment: ...why is that an issue?

Comment: What is the actual thing that is causing problems?  Do you WANT to lose souls to Miraak?

Comment: I believe this is the bug mentioned [here in the UESP wiki](http://uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:At_the_Summit_of_Apocrypha#Bugs). "*Sometimes Miraak will not absorb dragon souls, leaving him unable to heal himself and thus permanently ethereal during the fight as you steal all of his dragon souls.*"

Comment: The thing is that... Miraak never heals and he becomes ethereal and untargetable. So i can't complete the quest.

Comment: If you also have the Dawnguard and Hearthfire DLCs, or the Skyrim Legendary edition, then uninstall all the other 'unofficial patches' and try the [Unofficial Skyrim Legendary Edition Patch](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/71214/?) instead.

Comment: Are you using any mod?

Comment: I ain't, Just the Unofficial Patches

Answer (score 3):

Try one of these:

- Use the console command 'resurrect' or 'resethealth' to force him out of his ethereal form.
- Open the console (~), and type in "tcl" to turn clipping off. Head straight back to the original platform where you first encounter Sahrotaar, and head inside the dungeon and re-read "Chapter V" of the Black Book to teleport back to a previous dungeon. Upon loading back into the previous room, turn back around and re-read "Chapter VI" of the Black Book to return to the platform where you first ride Sahrotaar. With clipping still off, head back to the platform where you were fighting Miraak, and you should find Hermaeus Mora giving his final speech and you may continue with the quest.
- Go to your Skyrim data folder, then to scripts and delete mqkilldragonscript.pex and dragonactorscript.pex.
- Dragonrend Sahrotaar. Once he lands, kill him. After you kill him, Miraak should absorb Sahrotaar's soul, and the fight should continue.